# Want to run a script and have it be displayed on a terminal via cron on linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a sh script and want to see when it is being ran by opening a terminal the closing it at the end of the process because it will be showing the progress of a download. Im running linux

Answer (score 0):

This cron job does the trick:

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -- /bin/sleep 10s
```

Basically, set the display so that the command knows where to spawn the GUI, then run a terminal and tell *it* to run a command. Whether it'll work for you depends on which terminal you use and your display setup.